# Pin Facebook App to Page Tab

Tags: facebook

I'm creating simple app for my facebook fanpage and i have problems with pinning it to fanpage. So far I know it should be enabled in app center as "Page Tab" which I'm unable to do.

I have:
 * active app (public)
 * facebook canvas (filled canvas page, secure canvas url)
 * page tab (filled secure page tab url, page tab name, page tab edit url, page tab image)
 * in advanced checked: "Social Discovery", "Client OAuth Login", "Embedded browser OAuth Login"
 * in app details filled: "primary language", "tagline", "short description", "long description", "published", "category", whole "contact info" without App Page

And when i go to "App Center Listed Platforms" - option "Page Tab" is disabled.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add the app to a page tab, you can use the endpoint

```
POST /v2.2/{page-id}/tabs
```

with a HTTP request body of (replace the id with your actual `app_id`)

```
app_id=123456
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/tabs/#publish